# Is it possible to determine what properties a class has programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, language-design, introspection

Is it possible to determine what properties a class has programmatically? I want to see what properties a class (or subclass) has defined. I'm told this has to do with something called runtime introspection. I've found [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html), but it seems to be just the tip of the iceberg.

So, is it possible to determine what properties a class has programmatically? How?

**Edit:**

I'm working on iOS, not Mac OS X. What headers do I need to import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide includes [a section about listing properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html). The relevant snippet that actually gets the list is:

```
id LenderClass = objc_getClass("Lender");
unsigned int outCount;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(LenderClass, &outCount);
```

Then you use the runtime property functions to get whatever information you want about each property in the list.

Comment: Nevermind, you have to link against `libobjc.dylib` and `#import <objc/message.h>`.